# Saving Labels in NSUserDefault in Swift

Tags: swift, uilabel

So in the app I'm creating I have a settings view controller where users can type their information in the textfields and then when they click the done button it loads all that information to labels on the home view controller . How can I save the data in the home view controller with NSUserDefault? I'm using two view controllers.

**Settings View Controller**

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
            let DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! home
            DestViewController.NameText = NameTextField.text!
            DestViewController.positionText = positionTextField.text!
            DestViewController.divisionText = divisionTextField.text!
            DestViewController.routeText = routeTextField.text!
            DestViewController.routeText = routeTextField.text!
            DestViewController._picture = _picture.image!

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(NameTextField.text!, forKey: "name")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(positionTextField.text!, forKey: "position")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(divisionTextField.text!, forKey: "division")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(routeTextField.text!, forKey: "route")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(_picture, forKey: "ImageKey")
        }
```

**Home View Controller**

```
class home: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var Name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var position: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var division: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var route: UILabel!


   var contacts = MyContacts()
   var NameText = String()
   var positionText = String()
   var divisionText = String()
   var routeText = String()
   var _picture: UIImage!


   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

Name!.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("name")
position!.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("position")
division!.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("division")
route!.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("route")
Profile!.image = _picture
}
```

All of these codes work perfect, I'm just wondering if you could help me save the labels in NSUserDefault so every time the app is loaded all the information is still there. I've done a lot of research on this topic, but can find a solution for my problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use basic syntax:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(value, forKey:key)
```

Save example:-

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(positionTextField.text!, forKey: "position")
```

Retrieve example:-

```
position!.text=NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("position")
```

Note: remember the key must be unique.

Comment: @DoughnutMan Thanks

Comment: How would I save the image?

Comment: for JPEG
let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0)!
for PNG
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

and Save Like

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(imageData, forKey: "ImageKey")

Retervie Like
let image: UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData)
or
let image: UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData,scale:1.0)

Comment: @DoughnutMan Just save image into data
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.5) Or let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! and then save data in userdefault

Comment: Thanks!! Works perfectly!! You're the bomb!

Answer (score 0):

I have created following 2 functions which does Saving & Retrieving of Data using NSUserDefault. Refer it and use accordingly.

```
func saveDataInUserDefault()
{
    // *** init NSUserDefaults ***
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults()

    // *** Init a UIImage, you can use your UIImage instead ***
    let img = UIImage.init(imageLiteral: "image")

    // *** set values in UserDefault as well image ***
    userDefaults.setObject("value of name textfield", forKey: "name")
    userDefaults.setObject("value of position textfield", forKey: "position")
    userDefaults.setObject("value of division textfield", forKey: "division")
    userDefaults.setObject("value of route textfield", forKey: "route")
    // *** convert image to NSData and store it ***
    userDefaults.setObject(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0), forKey: "image")

    // *** save all the changes to NSUserDefaults ***
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}

func getDataFromUserDefaults()
{
    // *** Now lets access all the stored data from user default ***

    // *** init NSUserDefaults ***
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults()

    // *** to get normal objects use following ***
    print(userDefaults.objectForKey("name"))

    // *** to load image use following ***
    let img = UIImage(data:userDefaults.objectForKey("image") as! NSData)        
}
```

Comment: Do I put both of this functions in the home view controller?

Comment: Put saving function where you are setting and reading function where you want to retrieve.

Comment: So i updated my question. i figured out how to save the text. i just can't figure out how to save the `_picture` in NSUserDefault

Comment: I have explained it in both methods how to store UIImage in userdefault and retrieve back. Take a look at image key. You will get your solution.

Comment: you have to convert uimage to nsdata then u can save the same that is nsdata in nauserdefault.

Comment: then u can retrieve the nadata from the key value of nsuserdefault and convert the nsdata to uiimage again